# Creating a list of repeated elements

Tags: r, list, repeat

Here is a very naive function that creates a list of repeat elements

```
CreateListOfRepeatedElements = function(elem, n){
    l = list()
    for (i in 1:n){
        l[[i]] = elem   
    }
    return(l)
}

CreateListOfRepeatedElements(c(1,2,3), 4)
CreateListOfRepeatedElements(matrix(1:12, ncol=3), 3)
```

Is there a simpler alternative?

Comment: Yes, you can use `rep` or `replicate`

Comment: Ha ha. Indeed. I didn't even think the `rep` could have such behaviour. I used to use `rep` for vectors only. You can make an answer out of your comment. Thanks.

Comment: although `rep` won't create a list...

Comment: @RichardScriven good point. Works even with a simple `rep(list(1:3), 4)`

Comment: by the way it's better to use `lapply`, `sapply`, etc or `plyr` package to write loops instead of these C-like loops!